# Default wcf service application has no endpoint defined

Tags: c#, wcf

I just created a new WCF Service Application project in VS2010 (Premium), and it works out-of-the-box, but when I opened up the web.config file there are no endpoints present. The application works fine and I can open the address (http://localhost:50639/Service1.svc?wsdl) in a browser and I can see the contract and it all looks fine.

So my question is if the default project has uses a different approach rather then placing the  information in the web.config? I can't see anything in the code either.

To show my point this is all that the web.config contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false     and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the     value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception     information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And still this service works and I can both connect and call the default methods (e.g. GetData())

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not a "different" approach. It is a new approach in WCF 4.0 called [simplified configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014.aspx). If you create project in .NET 4.0 you will get this simplified mode. If you create project in .NET 3.5 you will get old chatty configuration.

Comment: Is this true for HTTPS? I could not find any references.

Comment: Sorry just tried it myself. Yes it works for HTTPs as well :)

Comment: Pretty easy, you just need to set the correct binding "TransportSecurity", certificates and correct binding. Simplified configuration would work in both HTTPs and non HTTPS.

Comment: Anyone know how to turn on the "chatty" version when creating a WCF service project? MS is not doing anyone favors by obfuscating the settings - especially for those of us trying to learn WCF.